# Mysql key reference

Tags: mysql

I need a help in MySQL key reference.

Look at my main table. For each value in tabel_name I have a new table created with that same name.

Table Name  : User_list

```
id  name  tabel_name    
1   aaa   tabel1
2   bbb   tabel2
```

Table Name : table1

```
id  country
1    US
2    IN
```

Table Name : table2

```
id  country
1    US
2    IN
```

Now, what I need is on deleting the record where id=1, table "table1" should be deleted.

Comment: u have to use cascade delete .or delete using join

Comment: is this possible through phpmyadmin?

Comment: i think u can use innodb as storage engine and use foreign key references

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to map to an entire table instead of a single row? Your example doesn't explain what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 2):

"For each value in table_name I have a new table created"

Don't do that. It's almost universally wrong:

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this is SQL.

May be it will work if use trigger for delete rows. But this is not correct way.
You should make this during other language, not SQL.

If you still need make this in SQL then is possible you have poor architecture of your database. And you should change it and optimize.